# Dynamically add component in react with hooks

Tags: reactjs

i have 3 components: Form (parent), Picklist and ParagraphBox (children); based on the select of the picklist, i render ParagraphBox and also a "+" button. What i would like to achieve is on the click of the plus button, render another ParagraphBox, just under the first. I would also like the remove functionality.

My ParagraphBox component has a title and a content, and i want to give the adding a progressive number:
e.g Paragraph 1
Content: ....
Paragraph 2
Content: ....
And so on
Here's my ParagraphBox component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export default function ParagraphBox(props) {

const [paragrafo, setParagrafo] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('paragrafo ', paragrafo)
    props.onChange(paragrafo)
}, [paragrafo])

const onChange = (e) => {
    const titolo = e.target.name
    const contenuto = e.target.value
    setParagrafo({
        ...paragrafo,
        [titolo]: contenuto
    })
}

return (
    <div className = "paragraph-box">
        <label>
            {props.labelInputBox}
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="titolo" value={paragrafo.titolo || ''} onChange={onChange}/>
            </div>
            {props.labelTextArea}
            <div>
                <textarea id="subject" name="contenuto" placeholder="Inserisci contenuto.." style={{height: "45x", width: "400px"}} value={paragrafo.contenuto || ''} onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
 )
}
```

Here is my Form component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './Form.css'
import createDocument from '../pdfTool';
import finalita from '../icons/finalita.PNG';
import Picklist from './Picklist.js';
import ParagraphBox from './ParagraphBox';




export default function Form() {
 
const [flagImg, setFlagImg] = useState(false)
const [flagPar, setFlagPar] = useState(false)
const [paragArray, setParagArray] = useState([
    {titolo: '', contenuto: ''}
])

const handleChange = (e) => {
    
    console.log('e ', e)
    console.log('e.titolo PARENT ', e.titolo)
    console.log('e.contenuto PARENT ', e.contenuto)
    setParagArray({
        ...paragArray,
        [e.titolo]: e.contenuto
    })
}


useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendering useEffect')
    console.log('flagPar: ', flagPar)
    console.log('flagImg: ', flagImg)
    console.log('paragArray ', paragArray)
}, [flagPar, flagImg, paragArray])

const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault(); //usato per evitrare il refresh del browser
}

const addParag = (parag) => {
    console.log('paragArray PARENT  ', paragArray)
    
    
}

const onSelect = (selectedValue) => {
    console.log('valore selezionato nella picklist: ' + selectedValue)
    if(selectedValue === 'Layout 2') {
        setFlagImg(true)
        setFlagPar(true)
    }
}

return(
    <div>
    <Picklist onSelect={onSelect} label="Seleziona un layout di contratto: "  pickVals={["Seleziona...", "Layout 1", "Layout 2", "Layout 3"]}/>
    {flagImg ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Picklist onSelect={onSelect} label="Seleziona Immagine: " pickVals={["Seleziona...", "Immagine 1", "Immagine 2", "Immagine 3"]} />
        </form>
    ) : null}
    {flagPar ? (
        <div>
            <ParagraphBox labelInputBox="Paragfrafo 1" labelTextArea="Contenuto Paragrafo" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <div id = "add-paragraph">
                <button type="button" onClick={addParag}>+</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>            
    ) : null}        
    </div>
)
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old...but I just faced the same issue, so here it goes: JSX is just syntactic sugar for regular JavaScript. Therefore you can just create the component manually and make it available as part of your hook, i.e.:

custom hook:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Advise from '../../components/Advise/Advise';

const useAdvise = () => {
    const [ showAdvise, setShowAdvise ] = useState(false)
    const [ adviseMsg, setAdviseMsg ] = useState('')
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false)

    const hideAdvise = () => {
        setShowAdvise(false)
    }

    const adviseComponent = React.createElement(Advise, {show:showAdvise, showSpinner:loading, hideAdvise:hideAdvise, children:adviseMsg})

    return {
        adviseComponent,
        setShowAdvise,
        setAdviseMsg,
        setLoading
    }
};

export default useAdvise;
```

component where I want it:

```js
import useAdvise  from '../hooks/useAdvise/useAdvise'

const Page = () => {

    const {adviseComponent, setShowAdvise, setAdviseMsg, setLoading} = useAdvise()
    
    return(
      <div>
        {adviseComponent}
      </div>
    )
}
```

hope it helps (cheers from Br as well)